# Multiple Inheritance in Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I need to connect my Android `Activity` with `SQLite` Database.

Now the problem is the `Class` for `Activity` will `extend` (inherit) `Activity` Class and for Database I need to inherit (`extend`) `SQLiteOpenHelper`, that is need to extend both classes at the same time.

So what should I do?

Comment: There is *no* MI in Java or Android. In this case you'll need to use "composition" for the SQLiteOpenHelper (and, well, create a class that is *different* from the Activity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate object that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Your activity can then delegate any calls to that object. However, there's no good reason for the `Activity` to be handling those calls at all; they should just go to the helper object.